# Set a javascript code as a variable

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I get a variable from the controller that is a java script code and want to init a variable of java script file with this data as a string.

What I mean is:

`Model.TrialScript` is equal to the string of:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var j = new Date();</script>
```

(I got it from the DB)

and then, I want to do the next thing in my js file:

```
var TrialScript = '<%= Model.TrialScript %>';
```

The problem is that `TrialScript` is not like I expect:

```
var TrialScript = '<script type="text/javascript">var j = new Date();
```

assuming I must get the js code as: `<script type="text/javascript">` and not:
`<script type=\"text/javascript\">`, how can I solve this issue?

Another thing may helps: I want to run this script only when the user press a button (is called: `button1`)

Maybe is there an option to call this script from the js after the button is clicked without saving this script as a variable?

any help appreciated!

Comment: The escaping is normal.

Comment: @Scunibster, thank you.. I know but how can I get the full js code? or maybe is there an option to call this script from the js after the button is clicked without saving this script as a variable?

Comment: You should have a look at the eval function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Comment: @mainguy, I know it but it doesnt get js code: <script type...>

Comment: Careful @mainguy There is a legion of hipsters here that would ban you for linking to w3schools

Comment: Leave out the <script type...> part. Just use the code.

Comment: @Claudio Uhh, thanks for the warning. This was just the first the thing I found. Won't do it amyore ...

Comment: You better make sure people can't abuse this to inject code. This just screams for a XSS leak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that way:

```
var TrialScript = '<%= Model.TrialScript %>';
//remove script tags, get only the code
TrialScript = TrialScript.replace(new RegExp("^<script.*?>(.*)</script>"), "$1");
// transform the code as a JS function
TrialScript = new Function(TrialScript);
// associate to the button1
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = TrialScript;
```